# Running the same query multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have been tasked to regenerate every class code, but there are over 4,000 and I'd rather not do that manually. I decided to make a test database with the same structure just to mess with it before I actually began messing with the live server.

I am having an issue trying to run the same query multiple times. I'd like to run it multiple times because I have a randomly generated string (that is also being generated every time this runs) that needs to replace other strings.

Any help, guys?

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $password = str_rand();
        $sql = "UPDATE test "
            . "SET classCode = '$password'".
            . "WHERE id = '$i'";
    }

    mysql_select_db('workshe3_worksheetwonder');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval ) {
        die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "All codes regenerated successfully.";
    mysql_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: what protocol you using? mysql_*? mysqli_*? PDO? any reason why don't you run the query written there in the loop?

Comment: What issue are you having with it?

Comment: MySQL. And the issue I am having is that it is only replacing the number before "$i < #;" so if it is 8, which it is, it'll only replace ID 7.

Comment: where do you run the query? outside the loop?

Comment: Well you're not performing the query in the loop, I'm guessing you're performing it after your loop (can't tell as it's not in the code you've posted). So basically your loop is just running 8 times, and replacing the string `$sql` each time until it hits `$i = 7` where it stops.

Comment: I don't know if your id field starts at zero - but your incremental index in the loop does. So, it loops eight times yes - but is only assigning 7 values since the first will likely encounter no match with an id of 0.

Comment: I edited my main post to show the query

Comment: simply execute the query in the loop!

Comment: You should switch to pdo or mysqli and prepared statements. It would make the query much more efficient.

Comment: is this `echo "All codes regenerated successfully.";` echoing 7 times?

Comment: For performance sake, use prepared statments if you want to execute the same query several times.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this

```
mysql_select_db('workshe3_worksheetwonder');

for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
  $password = str_rand();
  $sql = "
     UPDATE test 
     SET classCode = '$password'
     WHERE id = '$i'";

  $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "All codes regenerated successfully.";
```

`mysql_query()` is the function that needs to go in the loop, as it's the thing that's actually doing the updating. Your `$sql` is just a string with the command in it. If you don't run the `mysql_query()` in your loop then your string just gets overwritten without being used.

[mysql_ functions are deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), meaning you shouldn't really use them for new code. There are some examples of alternative protocols if you follow that link.

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue though, does it?

Comment: It should being doing so, this code will now run the query multiple times. If it's not, then you've got an issue elsewhere.